# spawn child process not exiting in node js

Tags: node.js, child-process

I am trying to create a child process in node js using following code

fileone.js

```
    var childProcess = require('child_process');

  var workerProcess = childProcess.spawn('node', ['api/filetwo.js', id]);
    workerProcess.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
     console.log('stdout: ' + data);
     //res.jsonp('hi output view in console');
    });

    workerProcess.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
       console.log('stderr: ' + data);
       res.jsonp('hi error occured');
    });

    workerProcess.on('close', function (code) {
       console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
       res.jsonp('hi process closed');
    });
```

filetwo.js

```
console.log("file two called");
```

if I run this piece of code I get message in console and response at client side 'hi process closed.'

I want to query database in child process so

filetwo.js

```
connection.query(query,function(error,result){
  if(error){
  console.log("error",error)
}else{
 console.log("result",result);
 console.log("Child Process " + process.argv[2] + " executed." );
}
})
```

I can see both console message in terminal but I don't get any response on client side. What am I missing please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

U should use IPC for master <-> child communication see https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_message and https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback

Comment: Thanks it helped. I used process.exit() in child.

Comment: @AMahajan Can you elaborate, how you resolved this issue?